# Inverse Laplace Transform of Third Order Denominator $\frac{s^2 -s -15} { s^3 +8s^2 +24s -32}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am trying to find the inverse laplace transform of the following function:
$$
f(s)=\frac{s^2 -s -15} { s^3 +8s^2 +24s -32} 
$$
I can't seem to factor the denominator to use partial fractions. Is there something I'm missing or another method to solve this? This is for a circuits class.

Comment: use $Latex$ please, i fixed it for you this time

Comment: Check where the equation comes from. There is probably a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot seem to find a nice expression for the roots, so I will outline a general *implicit* approach. Assuming that $\zeta_1,\zeta_2,\zeta_3$ are three distinct complex numbers and $q(s)$ is a second degree polynomial, non-vanishing over $\{\zeta_1,\zeta_2,\zeta_3\}$,
$$ f(s)=\frac{q(s)}{(s-\zeta_1)(s-\zeta_2)(s-\zeta_3)}=\sum_{k=1}^{3}\frac{\eta_k}{s-\zeta_k}\tag{1} $$
where
$$ \eta_k = \text{Res}_{s=\zeta_k}f(s) = \lim_{s\to \zeta_k}\frac{q(s)(s-\zeta_k)}{(s-\zeta_1)(s-\zeta_2)(s-\zeta_3)}=\frac{q(\zeta_k)}{(-1)^k \sqrt{D}}\tag{2} $$
with $D$ being a constant depending only on the discriminant of $(s-\zeta_1)(s-\zeta_2)(s-\zeta_3)$.
By applying $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ to the RHS of $(1)$ and exploiting $(2)$ we get
$$ (\mathcal{L}^{-1} f)(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{D}}\sum_{k=1}^{3}(-1)^k q(\zeta_k) e^{\zeta_k x}.\tag{3} $$
In particular, the behaviour of $\mathcal{L}^{-1}f$ in a left neighbourhood of $+\infty$ and the positions of $\zeta_1,\zeta_2,\zeta_3$ are deeply connected. In the given case $\zeta_1$ is close to $1$ and $\zeta_{2,3}$ are close to $-4.5\pm 3.5i$, hence $(\mathcal{L}^{-1} f)(x)$ is pretty close to $-\frac{15}{43}e^x$ for large values of $x$.